# Antisymmetry by equivalence

Tags: order-theory, equivalence-relations

Suppose you have a set with an equivalence relation $\equiv $ which is not the same as identity and a preorder $\leq$ such that

reflexive equiv $a\equiv a$

symmetric equiv $a\equiv b\rightarrow b\equiv a$

transitive equiv $a\equiv b\wedge b\equiv c\rightarrow a\equiv c$

reflexive leq $a\leq a$

pseud-antisymmetric leq $a\leq b\wedge b\leq a\rightarrow a\equiv b$

transitive leq $a\leq b\wedge b\leq c\rightarrow a\leq c$

There are, however, many pairs $a,b$ such that $a\leq b\wedge b\leq a\wedge a\neq b$.

How would this normally be treated? Would you call $\leq$ a partial order and just ignore the difference between $\equiv$ and $=$ or would you call this something else?

Also, I want this structure to impose a total order on the equivalence classes of $\equiv$. That is, let $x,y,z$ represent equivalences classes of $\equiv$ and let $x\leq y$ be defined as $\exists a\in x,b\in y.a\leq b$, then

$$x\leq x$$

$$x\leq y\wedge y\leq x\rightarrow x=y$$

$$x\leq y\wedge y\leq z\rightarrow x\leq z$$

$$x\leq y\vee y\leq x$$

From intuitions about the model I have in mind (geometric magnitudes) I believe that it should be possible to prove that this structure exists, but it isn't obvious to me how to do that.

Comment: do you also have $a\equiv b\implies a\leq b \wedge b\leq a$?  If so, then your preorder induces a partial order on the equivalence classes, so I would probably just name the original preorder with a weird symbol like $\preccurlyeq$ and then define $\leq$ to be the induced partial order on the equivalence classes.  Note that there is no reason to assume your induced partial order is a total order, not from your current listed axioms (even if you include the axiom I mentioned here, that's still not enough for total order).

Comment: Thank you @AnneBauval